# Can I use Docker arguments in the `from` flag of a Docker COPY statement?

Tags: docker

The following is the top of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG VERSION=dev
ARG DEPENDENCY_VERSION=latest

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
ARG DEPENDENCY_VERSION
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./web .
COPY --from=registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:${DEPENDENCY_VERSION} app/node_modules ./node_modules
```

The pipeline fails with an error `error building image: could not parse reference`. Am I messing something up or arguments are not allowed inside the `--from` flag?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the parameter in quotes like this: `COPY --from="registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:${DEPENDENCY_VERSION}" app/node_modules ./node_modules`

Comment: The format is correct https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-an-external-image-as-a-stage

Comment: I believe `ARG DEPENDENCY_VERSION` should not be used a second time. It overrides and default value is not  `latest` unless u pass it during the build

Comment: @n1md7 declaring a second time is needed because `ARG`s are scoped per build stage.

Comment: Ah, I see, Makes sense. What if env var is used additionally? like `ENV DEPENDENCY_VERSION =${DEPENDENCY_VERSION:-latest}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it as a multi-stage build like this and it works:

```
ARG VERSION=dev
ARG DEPENDENCY_VERSION=latest

FROM registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:${DEPENDENCY_VERSION} AS src_image

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./web .
COPY --from=src_image app/node_modules ./node_modules
```